# Or queries not supported spring data dynamodb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I'm just trying to query by using spring data, and some of the "findBy" queries. Underneath, we are calling a DynamoDB database.

I have an interface like this:

```
import org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.EnableScan;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import es.viesgo.ciegen.persistence.Parameter;

@EnableScan
public interface ParameterRepository extends CrudRepository<Parameter, String> ,  ParameterRepositoryCustom {

List<Parameter> findByParameterOrStartdatevalidityOrEnddatevalidity(String parameter, String startdatevalidity, String enddatevalidity);
```

But when I call this findBy method, following error is raised:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Or queries not supported
```

Current versions I'm using in my pom.xml for spring-boot is 1.5.10 and for spring-data-dynamodb is 4.5.0

Are these findBy...Or... methods really not supported? is there a newer version of them with this support?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hard to tell but Spring is likely executing a Query request (as opposed to Scan or GetItem)

A Query request allows you to set a KeyConditionExpression but there are some restrictions on how the expression is formed. You can read all of the details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) but just to highlight a couple parts:

> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key value
>
> The condition can optionally perform one of several comparison tests on a single sort key value.

The main take away here is you can only use a *single* partition key value and a *single* sort key value in your query. This automatically means that OR cannot be supported since that would require multiple values.

A Query request also allows you to set a FilterExpression which can use OR however the FilterExpression gets applied after the KeyConditonExpression, in other words, after the item has already been read from disk.

Comment: But instead of using a Query request, it should be able to use Scan so you can achieve that behaviour, or am I wrong? I'm new to DynamoDB, so maybe I am mistaken here

Comment: You are using a framework to communicate with DynamoDB so it's difficult to say what it is doing under the hood. I'm almost certain it isn't going to use Scan. What Scan does is basically look at *each* record in the table and execute the optional query condition. If the record passes the condition, it is added to the result set. Once DynamoDB has scanned 1MB of data the result set is returned. If there are more records to scan, Dynamo also returns a LastEvaluatedKey. Since this is not very efficient, I doubt it is what you want. There are some use cases for it however.